# Update NULL filled rows for a column based on matching values of other columns in other rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose I have a dataframe as below:

`df1=
    name    street   city  coordinates
0   A0      B0       C0    1,1
1   A1      B0       C0    NaN
2   A2      B0       C0    NaN
3   A3      B2       C2    NaN
4   A4      B2       C2    2,3
5   A5      B3       C3    NaN
6   A6      B3       C3    NaN`

I want the result to be

`df1=
    name    street   city  coordinates
0   A0      B0       C0    1,1
1   A1      B0       C0    1,1
2   A2      B0       C0    1,1
3   A3      B2       C2    2,3
4   A4      B2       C2    2,3
5   A5      B3       C3    NaN
6   A6      B3       C3    NaN`

I want to update ***coordinates*** with the same ***street*** and ***city***.
In the above example (B0,C0) at index 0 has coordinates (1,1). So I need to update coordinates at indices 1 and 2 to (1,1) since they have same street and city(B0,C0).
What is the best way to achieve this?

Also how do I update all the dataframes in similar fashion if we are given a list of dataframes. i.e
`df_list = [df1,df2,..]`

Is it a good idea to first generate a dataframe with unique rows from all the dataframes and then use this dataframe for look-up and update each dataframe?

Comment: Can you explain why the last two values in `coordinates` are NaN's? Should it be `2,3`?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If only one non `NaN` value in each group is possible use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with `ffill` ([`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `method='ffill'`):

```
df = df.sort_values(['street','city','coordinates'])
df['coordinates'] = df['coordinates'].ffill()
print (df)
  name street city coordinates
0   A0     B0   C0         1,1
1   A1     B0   C0         1,1
2   A2     B0   C0         1,1
4   A4     B2   C2         2,3
3   A3     B2   C2         2,3
5   A5     B2   C2         2,3
5   A6     B2   C2         2,3
```

Solution with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df['coordinates'] = df.groupby(['street','city'])['coordinates']
                      .transform(lambda x: x.dropna())
print (df)
  name street city coordinates
0   A0     B0   C0         1,1
1   A1     B0   C0         1,1
2   A2     B0   C0         1,1
3   A3     B2   C2         2,3
4   A4     B2   C2         2,3
5   A5     B2   C2         2,3
5   A6     B2   C2         2,3
```

Or [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html) with [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.bfill.html):

```
df['coordinates'] = df.groupby(['street','city'])['coordinates']
                      .transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
  name street city coordinates
0   A0     B0   C0         1,1
1   A1     B0   C0         1,1
2   A2     B0   C0         1,1
3   A3     B2   C2         2,3
4   A4     B2   C2         2,3
5   A5     B2   C2         2,3
5   A6     B2   C2         2,3
```

Second solution works with multiple values also - first forward fill values per group (not replace first values, stay `NaN`) and then all first values replace by back filling:

```
print (df)
  name street city coordinates
0   A0     B0   C0         1,1
1   A1     B0   C0         NaN
2   A2     B0   C0         NaN
3   A3     B2   C2         NaN
4   A4     B2   C2         2,3
5   A5     B2   C2         4,7
5   A6     B2   C2         NaN

df['coordinates'] = df.groupby(['street','city'])['coordinates']
                      .transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
  name street city coordinates
0   A0     B0   C0         1,1
1   A1     B0   C0         1,1
2   A2     B0   C0         1,1
3   A3     B2   C2         2,3
4   A4     B2   C2         2,3
5   A5     B2   C2         4,7
5   A6     B2   C2         4,7
```

Comment: how to update list of dataframes? i.e if coordinates are present in any of the dataframes in the list, update all the rows with NULL values and matching other columns in all the dataframes.

Comment: I think you need concat all dataframes together with parameter keys first, apply solution and then split them.

Comment: Can you help me splitting the combined dataframe back to list of dataframes? I am stuck after doing below:


df = pd.cancat(df_list, ignore_index=False)


df['coordinates'] = df.groupby(['street','city'])['coordinates']
                      .transform(lambda x: x.dropna())

Comment: You can try `L = [x.reset_index(level=0, drop=True) for i, x in df.groupby(level=0)]`

Comment: The solution using groupby and transform does not work when dataframe has
`[A5      B3       C3    NaN], [A6      B3       C3    NaN]`
I get 'ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 2' error. Sorry to point this late :(

Comment: What solution do you use? with dropna?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150383/discussion-between-nbbk-and-jezrael).